# Is there any option to see how many vertex and faces are on my individual models in Blender 2.92

Tags: vertices, polycount

[image]

After activating the Statistics option it shows the total polycount in the viewport. is there any way to see individual objects' polycount? I was wondering is there any way where I can see separately after clicking individual objects polycount. I would like to know is there any option to see how many vertex and faces are on my individual models.

Comment: Hello :). Simply select your object and switch to Edit mode.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to upvote the answers that helped you :)